# Find out if a particular user logs in every day

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I find out if a particular user log ins every day using SQL in MySQL?

I have a table like this.

```
+----------+---------------------+---------+
| login_id | login_date          | user_id |
+----------+---------------------+---------+
|     8494 | 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |   20703 |
|    22403 | 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |   53473 |
|    23965 | 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |   79722 |
|    30173 | 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |   36396 |
|    34928 | 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |   20703 |
|    38740 | 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |   15758 |
|    42769 | 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |   79722 |
|    44364 | 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |   79722 |
|    45440 | 2016-03-03 00:00:00 |   20703 |
|    49050 | 2016-03-03 00:00:00 |   36396 |
|    50273 | 2016-03-03 00:00:00 |   79722 |
|    50344 | 2016-03-04 00:00:00 |   20703 |
|    51360 | 2016-03-04 00:00:00 |   20703 |
|    54404 | 2016-03-04 00:00:00 |   53473 |
|    61533 | 2016-03-04 00:00:00 |   79722 |
|    72852 | 2016-03-05 00:00:00 |   20703 |
|    74546 | 2016-03-05 00:00:00 |   38289 |
|    76487 | 2016-03-05 00:00:00 |   62529 |
|    82439 | 2016-03-05 00:00:00 |   36396 |
|    90006 | 2016-03-05 00:00:00 |   36396 |
|    90404 | 2016-03-06 00:00:00 |   20703 |
+----------+---------------------+---------+
```

And the answer would be something like

```
user_id, consecutive
20703, 'YES'
53473, 'NO'
```

20703 logins everyday from 2016-03-01 - 2016-03-06 but 53473 only logged in twice. the range is going to be from the start to finish of the entire table.

Comment: 53473 logged in twice. so 'NO' means there is a a minimum number of consecutive days to mark in 'YES' ?

Comment: The number of distinct daily logins will be equal to the difference in days between the start and end date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do:

```
select user_id,
       ( count(distinct login_date) = cnt_ld ) as everyday_flag
from t cross join
     (select count(distinct login_date) as cnt_ld
      from t
     ) tt
group by user_id, tt.cnt_ld;
```

Note that this compares a user to all days *in the table*.  If one day has no logins and you still want to include that day, then use the maximum minus the minimum for the comparison.

This also returns a "boolean" flag (really 0 or 1).  You can use `case` to convert this to `'YES'`/`'NO'`, but I find the number easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I get the max and min date in  tbl then if the count per user id is equal to the datediff between max and min date (+1 day) then it is consecutive login else no.

```
select t1.user_id, 
    case when count(*)=datediff(t2.maxdt, t2.mindt)+1
    then 'YES' else 'NO'  end as consecutive
from tbl t1
join (select max(login_date) as maxdt,
             min(login_date) as mindt
          from tbl) t2
group by t1.user_id
order by t1.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just simply use `group by` with `case` expressions to find consecutive logins

```
select user_id, 
       case when count(distinct login_date) <> datediff(max(login_date), min(login_date))+1
            then 'No' else 'Yes' end consecutive
from table t
group by user_id
```

If, you want to find users which has consecutive logins with start date to end date, then you could also do that via `cross joins`.

```
select user_id, case when counts <> total_counts then 'No' else 'Yes' end consecutive 
from (select t.user_id, count(distinct login_date) counts
      from table t 
      group by t.user_id )t cross join (
select count(distinct login_date) total_counts from table) tt
```